How to filter channels via pattern parameter in centrifugo channels method
Im using centrifugo server and I have channels like this:
{
   "admin":{"num_clients":2},
   "admin#101":{"num_clients":1},
   "admin#202":{"num_clients":1},
   "user":{"num_clients":2},
   "user#303":{"num_clients":1},
   "user#404":{"num_clients":1}
}

As you can see, admin#id and user#id is pattern, in production can be mire than 2000 channels
For optimization to get only user#id channels or admin#id I would like to use parameter pattern from official docs
But it doesnt work correct, I send user or user# and centrifugo dont return all (user#id) channels
Centrifugo return only "user" main channel, please help
I tried to use user or user# pattern, there no docs about that parameter

After spent time to try combinations of symbols I found what work
Need to use pattern like admin#*, so the char * working
The question is why this not in the docs?
